# consulta básica sql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, mysql-workbench

creo que es muy básico pero no tengo mucho conocimiento en SQL, tengo dos tablas

> usuarios
>
> - id
> - nombre
>
> amistad

> - envio amistad (fk de id usuario) esta se relaciona con la id de usuarios
> - recibio amistad (fk de id usuario)esta se relaciona con la id de usuarios

al hacer `SELECT * FROM  AMISTAD`
ME MUESTRA
EJEMPLO

| id | envio amistad | recibio amistad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |

yo quiero que muestre los nombres

| id | envio amistad | recibio amistad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | juan | pepe |

como debería ser la consulta ?

Comment: redacta mejor tu pregunta, los nombres de las 2 tablas, si existe relación entre ellas en fin que podamos identificar mejor para ayudar

Comment: Normalmente se usa JOIN, yo uso el where directamente, lo veo más claro. Sería algo así como SELECT * FROM amistad, usuarios WHERE amistad.envio_uid = usuarios.id; siendo envio_uid el id del usuario a relacionar.

Comment: El problema debería resolverse con la respuesta de @aloMalbarez . Para evitar tener que escribir consultas confusas,  u otros problemas, considera evitar el uso de nombres de columna del tipo `envio amistad`, `recibio amistad`. Los nombres de columnas deben ser descriptivos, pero también funcionales y lo menos propensos posible a errores. Si estás en la tabla `amistad`, con que llames a tus columnas `envio`  y `recibio`, lo de *amistad*  sobraría. Si de todos modos lo quieres conservar, puedes unirlas por `_`,  o sea: `envio_amistad`, `recibio_amistad`,  así, todo irá mejor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enlazar las tablas por id y tomar los nombres

```
SELECT a.id, u1.nombre 'envio amistad', u2.nombre 'recibio amistad' 
  FROM amistad AS a
LEFT JOIN usuarios u1 ON (a.'envio amistad'=u1.id)
LEFT JOIN usuarios u2 ON (a.'recibio amistad'=u2.id)
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me resulto perfecto !!!